# extracting data from the tweets of the twitter using python

Tags: python, twitter, extract

I want to extract data like tweet id , twitter username, twitter id of the user who has fb.me link displayed in his tweet and also his fb id and fb username.

I have to do this for 200 such tweets.

My code :

```
from twitter.oauth import OAuth
import json
import urllib2
from twitter import *

ckey = ''
csecret = '' 
atoken = '' 
asecret = ''



auth = OAuth(atoken,asecret,ckey,csecret)

t_api = Twitter(auth=auth)

search = t_api.search.tweets(q='http://on.fb.me',count=1)

print search

print 'specific data'

#print search['statuses'][0]['entities']['urls']
```

right now retrieving 1 result and want to extract the data above mentioned.

Result I got :

```
{u'search_metadata': {u'count': 1, u'completed_in': 0.021, u'max_id_str': u'542227367834685440', u'since_id_str': u'0', u'next_results': u'?max_id=542227367834685439&q=http%3A%2F%2Fon.fb.me&count=1&include_entities=1', u'refresh_url': u'?since_id=542227367834685440&q=http%3A%2F%2Fon.fb.me&include_entities=1', u'since_id': 0, u'query': u'http%3A%2F%2Fon.fb.me', u'max_id': 542227367834685440L}, u'statuses': [{u'contributors': None, u'truncated': False, u'text': u'Check out Monday Morning Cooking Club Cooking Tip Day #1 --&gt;http://t.co/j6mbg1OE6Z | http://t.co/c7qjunLQz2', u'in_reply_to_status_id': None, u'id': 542227367834685440L, u'favorite_count': 0, u'source': u'<a href="http://www.hootsuite.com" rel="nofollow">Hootsuite</a>', u'retweeted': False, u'coordinates': None, u'entities': {u'symbols': [], u'user_mentions': [], u'hashtags': [], u'urls': [{u'url': u'http://t.co/j6mbg1OE6Z', u'indices': [63, 85], u'expanded_url': u'http://on.fb.me/', u'display_url': u'on.fb.me'}, {u'url': u'http://t.co/c7qjunLQz2', u'indices': [88, 110], u'expanded_url': u'http://bit.ly/12BbG16', u'display_url': u'bit.ly/12BbG16'}]}, u'in_reply_to_screen_name': None, u'in_reply_to_user_id': None, u'retweet_count': 0, u'id_str': u'542227367834685440', u'favorited': False, u'user': {u'follow_request_sent': False, u'profile_use_background_image': True, u'profile_text_color': u'333333', u'default_profile_image': False, u'id': 226140415, u'profile_background_image_url_https': u'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_background_images/704964581/bc37b358019be05efe1094a0d100ea53.jpeg', u'verified': False, u'profile_location': None, u'profile_image_url_https': u'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/469488950050955264/FOoWjIEZ_normal.jpeg', u'profile_sidebar_fill_color': u'DDEEF6', u'entities': {u'url': {u'urls': [{u'url': u'http://t.co/sida0E6eXy', u'indices': [0, 22], u'expanded_url': u'http://www.mondaymorningcookingclub.com.au', u'display_url': u'mondaymorningcookingclub.com.au'}]}, u'description': {u'urls': []}}, u'followers_count': 1574, u'profile_sidebar_border_color': u'000000', u'id_str': u'226140415', u'profile_background_color': u'EDCDC7', u'listed_count': 50, u'is_translation_enabled': False, u'utc_offset': 39600, u'statuses_count': 12594, u'description': u"Monday Morning Cooking Club. A bunch of Sydney gals sharing and preserving the wonderful recipes of Australia's culturally diverse Jewish community.", u'friends_count': 1904, u'location': u'Sydney,  Australia', u'profile_link_color': u'C40A38', u'profile_image_url': u'http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/469488950050955264/FOoWjIEZ_normal.jpeg', u'following': False, u'geo_enabled': True, u'profile_banner_url': u'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/226140415/1400769931', u'profile_background_image_url': u'http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_background_images/704964581/bc37b358019be05efe1094a0d100ea53.jpeg', u'name': u'Lisa Goldberg', u'lang': u'en', u'profile_background_tile': False, u'favourites_count': 1309, u'screen_name': u'MondayMorningCC', u'notifications': False, u'url': u'http://t.co/sida0E6eXy', u'created_at': u'Mon Dec 13 12:22:13 +0000 2010', u'contributors_enabled': False, u'time_zone': u'Sydney', u'protected': False, u'default_profile': False, u'is_translator': False}, u'geo': None, u'in_reply_to_user_id_str': None, u'possibly_sensitive': False, u'lang': u'en', u'created_at': u'Tue Dec 09 08:00:53 +0000 2014', u'in_reply_to_status_id_str': None, u'place': None, u'metadata': {u'iso_language_code': u'en', u'result_type': u'recent'}}]}
```

can you please help me out how to retrieve this particular data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this to issue a query and afterwards get the data you want by querying with the corresponding keys.

```
import json
import urllib2
import twitter

ckey = 'Your consumer key'
csecret = 'your consumer secret' 
atoken = 'your token' 
asecret = 'your secret token'

auth = twitter.oauth.OAuth(atoken, asecret,
                           ckey, csecret)

twitter_api = twitter.Twitter(auth=auth)

q = 'http://on.fb.me'

count = 100

search_results = twitter_api.search.tweets(q=q, count=count)

statuses = search_results['statuses']

# Iterate through 5 more batches of results by following the cursor

for _ in range(5):
    print "Length of statuses", len(statuses)
    try:
        next_results = search_results['search_metadata']['next_results']
    except KeyError, e: # No more results when next_results doesn't exist
        break

    # Create a dictionary from next_results, which has the following form:
    # ?max_id=313519052523986943&q=NCAA&include_entities=1
    kwargs = dict([ kv.split('=') for kv in next_results[1:].split("&") ])

    search_results = twitter_api.search.tweets(**kwargs)
    statuses += search_results['statuses']

# Show one sample search result by slicing the list...
print json.dumps(statuses[0], indent=1)

# get relevant data into lists
user_names = [ user_mention['name'] 
                 for status in statuses
                     for user_mention in status['entities']['user_mentions'] ]

screen_names = [ user_mention['screen_name'] 
                 for status in statuses
                     for user_mention in status['entities']['user_mentions'] ]

id_str = [ user_mention['id_str'] 
                 for status in statuses
                     for user_mention in status['entities']['user_mentions'] ]

t_id = [ status['id'] 
         for status in statuses ]

# print out first 5 results
print json.dumps(screen_names[0:5], indent=1) 
print json.dumps(user_names[0:5], indent=1)
print json.dumps(id_str[0:5], indent=1)
print json.dumps(t_id[0:5], indent=1)
```

Result:

```
[
 "DijalogNet", 
 "Kihot_ex_of", 
 "Kihot_ex_of", 
 "JAsunshine1011", 
 "RobertCornegyJr"
]
[
 "Dijalog Net", 
 "Sa\u0161a Jankovi\u0107", 
 "Sa\u0161a Jankovi\u0107", 
 "Raycent Edwards", 
 "Robert E Cornegy, Jr"
]
[
 "2380692464", 
 "563692937", 
 "563692937", 
 "15920807", 
 "460051837"
]
[
 542309722385580032, 
 542227367834685440, 
 542202885514461185, 
 542201843448045568, 
 542188061598437376
]
```

Have a look [at this site](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/furukama/Mining-the-Social-Web-2nd-Edition/blob/master/ipynb/Chapter%201%20-%20Mining%20Twitter.ipynb) for more examples on how to use the api.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable post. I have done this part already. I have a doubt the two ids that your are retrieving, according to me second one is tweet id and twitter id should be ['user']['id']. But can you tell me how to retrieve facebook user id and facebook username corresponding to the twitter user? Because that is my main concern.

Comment: I think the fb-account of the tweeting user is obscured. The only thing you can do is, check the tweet itself for fb-links and from there use the facebook api to determine the user that made the post (however, this doesn't have to be the original tweeting user). I'm unfamiliar with the facebook api, so I can't tell of potential  limitations.

Comment: can you specify the types of two ids that you retrieved  as user id and tweet id . also, will you please go through user array within the result that i posted in the question ?